# How to know where in the world is 8am

Tags: php, time, timezone

i have a little idea for a website and the main question to resolve is:

When a visitor came to the site, it has to know where in the world is 8 AM.

We always ask for "what time is it" in some place.

In a programatic way (PHP, for example). How we as the inverse question?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to write code to calculate it !

Comment: @TobyAllen of course, is the idea ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to start with a list of time zones, which you can get from:

```
DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL)
```

Then iterate through the list, and get the current time in each zone.

If the time is in the range you are looking for, then add the zone to a list of values to return.  It will be a *range* - you can't just say "where is it 8:00" - because hitting that mark on the nose would be extremely difficult.  You might instead say "where is it greater than or equal to 8:00 and less than 9:00".

This is a reasonably large bit of code that you should write yourself.  I gave you the starting point and the logic.  I think you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the local time, e.g it's 20:30 here in France. The timezone is currently is UTC or GMT+2 in summer.

You need to have a map which associates every timezone to locations and take the timezone `+2 - 12` here (because there's an offset of 12 hours with the location where it's 8a.m). So you need to show every country/cities where the timezone is GMT-10.

There's some cases to work around, e.g Australia where there's half timezone (even quarter! UTC +8:45 if I remember), but the idea is here.

If you want a *simple algorithm*, don't take minutes in account, because if you take a simple scheme where every timezone are full-hour, you'll have a region where it's 8a.m o'clock only when every clocks in the world are at :00 :-)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that many time zones do not have fixed offsets, and the dates that they switch from one offset to another are different per zone.  So just matching the time zones by their offsets is problematic.  You have to match by their *current* offset, which means you might as well iterate through them and calculate on each one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone. I needed to send an email at between 17:00-19:00 every day, depending on the user's *country*, which was obtained through a register form. I ended up with only a two-letter country code for every user. (My customer was ok with all US users having the same timezone for the time being.) After some looking around I ended up with the following:

1. An array with UTC offsets as key and an array of two-letter country codes for each one.

   ```
   $timezones_countries = array(
   '0' => array(
       'BF', // Burkina Faso
       'CI', // Côte d'Ivoire
       'DK', // Denmark,
       'ES', // Spain
       'GM', // Gambia
       'GH', // Ghana
       'GN', // Guinea
       'GW', // Guinea-Bissau
       'IS', // Iceland
       'IE', // Ireland
       'LR', // Liberia
       'MA', // Morocco
       'ML', // Mali
       'MR', // Mauritania
       'PT', // Portugal
       'SN', // Senegal
       'SL', // Sierra Leone
       'ST', // São Tomé and Príncipe
       'TG', // Togo
       'UK'  // United Kingdom
   ),
   '1' => array(
       'AD', // Andorra
       'AL', // Albania
       'AO', // Angola
       'AT', // Austria
       'BA', // Bosnia and Herzegovina
       'BE', // Belgium
       'BJ', // Benin
       'CF', // Central African Republic
       'CG', // Congo
       'CH', // Switzerland
       'CM', // Cameroon
       'CZ', // Czech Republic
       'DE', // Deutschland
       'DZ', // Algeria
       'FR', // France
       'GA', // Gabon
       'GQ', // Equatorial Guinea
       'HR', // Croatia
       'HU', // Hungary
       'IT', // Italy
       'LI', // Lichtenstein
       'LU', // Lucembourg
       'MC', // Monaco
       'ME', // Montenegro
       'MK', // Macedonia
       'MT', // Malta
       'NA', // Namibia
       'NE', // Niger
       'NG', // Nigeria
       'NO', // Norway
       'PL', // Poland
       'SE', // Sweden
       'SI', // Slovenia
       'SK', // Slovakia
       'SM', // San Marino
       'RS', // Serbia
       'TD', // Chad
       'TN', // Tunisia
       'VA'  // Vatican City
   ),
   '2' => array(
       'BG', // Bulgaria
       'BI', // Burundi
       'BW', // Botswana
       'CY', // Cyprus
       'EE', // Estonia
       'EG', // Egypt
       'GR', // Greece
       'FI', // Finland
       'IL', // Israel
       'JO', // Jordan
       'LB', // Lebanon
       'LS', // Lesotho
       'LT', // Lithuania
       'LV', // Latvia
       'LY', // Lybia
       'MD', // Moldova
       'MW', // Malawi
       'MZ', // Mozambique
       'RO', // Romania
       'RW', // Rwanda
       'SY', // Syria
       'SZ', // Swaziland
       'TR', // Turkey
       'UA', // Ukraine
       'ZA', // South Africa
       'ZM', // Zambia
       'ZW', // Zimbabwe
   ),
   '3' => array(
       'BH', // Bahrain
       'BY', // Belarus
       'DJ', // Djibouti
       'ER', // Eritrea
       'ET', // Ethiopia
       'IQ', // Iraq
       'KE', // Kenya
       'KW', // Kuwait
       'KM', // Comoros
       'MG', // Madagascar
       'QA', // Qatar
       'SA', // Saudi Arabia
       'SD', // Sudan
       'SO', // Somalia
       'SS', // South Sudan
       'TZ', // Tanzania
       'UG', // Uganda
       'YE'  // Yemen
   ),
   '4' => array(
       'AE', // United Arab Emirates
       'AM', // Armenia
       'AZ', // Azerbaijan
       'GE', // Georgia
       'IR', // Iran
       'MU', // Mauritius
       'OM', // Oman
       'RU', // Russia
       'SC', // Seychelles
   ),
   '5' => array(
       'AF', // Afghanistan
       'KZ', // Kazakhstan
       'MV', // Maldives
       'PK', // Pakistan
       'TJ', // Tajikistan
       'TM', // Turkmenistan
       'UZ'  // Uzbekistan
   ),
   '6' => array(
       'BD', // Bangladesh
       'BT', // Bhutan
       'IN', // India
       'LK', // Sri Lanka
       'KG', // Kyrgyzstan
       'NP', // Nepal
   ),
   '7' => array(
       'ID', // Indonesia
       'KH', // Cambodia
       'LA', // Laos
       'MM', // Myanmar
       'TH', // Thailand
       'VN'  // Vietnam
   ),
   '8' => array(
       'BN', // Brunei
       'CN', // China
       'MN', // Mongolia
       'MY', // Malaysia
       'PH', // Philippines
       'SG', // Singapore
       'TW'  // Taiwan
   ),
   '9' => array(
       'JP', // Japan
       'KP', // North Korea
       'KR', // South Korea
       'PW', // Palau
       'TP'  // East Timor
   ),
   '10' => array(
       'AU', // Australia
       'FM', // Federated States of Micronesia
       'MP', // Northern Mariana Islands
       'PG'  // Papua New Guinea
   ),
   '11' => array(
       'SB', // Solomon Islands
       'VU'  // Vanuatu
   ),
   '12' => array(
       'FJ', // Fiji
       'KI', // Kiribati
       'MH', // Marshall Islands
       'NF', // Norfolk Island
       'NR', // Nauru
       'NZ', // New Zealand
       'TV'  // Tuvalu
   ),
   '13' => array(
       'TO', // Tonga
       'WS'  // Samoa

   ),
   '-12' => array(),
   '-11' => array(
       'AS', // American Samoa
       'NU'  // Niue
   ),
   '-10' => array(
       'PF'  // French Polynesia
   ),
   '-9' => array(),
   '-8' => array(),
   '-7' => array(),
   '-6' => array(
       'BZ', // Belize
       'CR', // Costa Rica
       'GT', // Guatemala
       'HN', // Honduras
       'MX', // Mexico
       'NI', // Nicaragua
       'SV'  // El Salvador
   ),
   '-5' => array(
       'BS', // Bahamas
       'CA', // Canada
       'CO', // Colombia
       'CU', // Cuba
       'EC', // Ecuador
       'HT', // Haiti
       'JM', // Jamaica
       'KY', // Cayman Islands
       'PA', // Panama
       'PE', // Peru
       'TC', // Turks and Caicos Islands
       'US'  // United States
   ),
   '-4' => array(
       'AG', // Antigua and Barbuda
       'AW', // Aruba
       'BB', // Barbados
       'BM', // Bermuda
       'BO', // Bolivia
       'CL', // Chile
       'DM', // Dominica
       'DO', // Dominican Republic
       'GD', // Grenada
       'GP', // Guadeloupe
       'GY', // Guyana
       'KN', // Saint Kitts and Nevis
       'LC', // Saint Lucia
       'MQ', // Martinique
       'MS', // Montserrat
       'PR', // Puerto Rico
       'PY', // Paraguay
       'TT', // Trinidad and Tobago
       'VC', // Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
       'VE', // Venezuela
       'VG', // British Virgin Islands
       'VI'  // US Virgin Islands
   ),

       '-3' => array(
       'AR', // Argentina
       'BR', // Brazil
       'FK', // Falkland Islands
       'GL', // Greenland
       'GF', // French Guiana
       'SR', // Suriname
       'UY'  // Uruguay
   ),
   '-2' => array(
       'GS'  // South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
   ),
   '-1' => array(
       'CV'  // Cape Verde
   ));
   ```
2. A function that returns the array of countries (if any) where it's now between 17:00 and 19:00. The server time is UTC. I'm sure it could be made more efficient (Suggestions, anyone? :) ).

   ```
   function getTimezoneCountryCodes() {
       $offset = -12;
       $server_time = time();
       $countries = null;
       //echo 'UTC: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$server_time)."\n";
       while($offset < 12) {
           $delta_time = $offset * 3600;
           $trigger_time = $server_time + $delta_time;
           $hour = date('H', $trigger_time);
           if($hour == 17) {
               global $timezones_countries;
               $result = array(
                   'time'      => $trigger_time,
                   'countries' => $timezones_countries[strval($offset)]
               );
               return $result;
           }
           $offset++;
       }
   }
   $timezone = getTimezoneCountryCodes();
   ```

If you need precision for every country you'll need a more thorough approach.

Cheers